# How to perform a svn ci with files that have an M before them…?

Tags: svn

I have a directory that is in our svn repository. On my local system, I have modified several files (after performing an svn up this morning to get the latest changes.)

When I try to perform a commit, I get a list of my modified files back with the letter M as a prefix, and the commit does not seem to complete. What do I need to do to accomplish my commit?

Obviously, I am no svn genius (yet….)

TIA for any and all assistance!

Regards,

Steve O'Sullivan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That list is probably the editor where you can enter a commit message. Enter a short informative message above

```
--This line, and those below, will be ignored--
M    file1
```

(press `i` to get into text input mode in vi) and save (`:wq` in vi). You can change your editor by setting the `EDITOR` environment variable (or use the `--editor-cmd` option), or giving a commit message on the command line:

```
svn ci -m 'implement foobar'
```